# Improve search functionality in Android application?

Tags: php, android

I have implemented search functionality in my application, but search is not clear enough.

That means if user searches for other users, he need for example to type full first name, but in some cases where characters are foreign language in the middle of first name, like this one `Du*š*an` than it will display data after that character is typed, but if the case is `John`, then you need to type John for getting some results.

I want to display data after two or three characters are typed, and also i would like to clear list when no results are found.

One more thing to be mentioned, i'm doing searching with `EditText` widget.

This is how my code looks in java:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
        doSearch(s.toString());
    } else {
        // Probably here i need to clear list
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Now here is method for parsing network response:

```
private void doSearch(String query) {
    // showLoadingDialog();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("searchQuery", query);

    mNetworkManager.sendPostRueqestWithoutAuthentication(
            "http://192.168.42.6:8081/timster/include/Search.php",
            volleySuccessListener,
            volleyErrorListener,
            params);
}
```

And this is how i'm getting JSON response from DB:

```
private VolleyListenerSuccess volleySuccessListener = new VolleyListenerSuccess() {
    @Override
    public void getResult(String response) {
        // dialog.dismiss();
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no rows")) {
            // TODO change recycler view state
            // Here i should clear list too
            mUsers.clear();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    User user         = new User();
                    user.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    user.setImage(object.getString("image"));
                    mUsers.add(user);
                }

                mAdapter = new UserListAdapterV3(activity, mUsers);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Should i change something here too?
This is server side code (PHP):

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['searchQuery']))
{
  require_once('ConfigV2.php');
  $search_query=$_POST['searchQuery'];
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST(:search_query)';
  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->bindParam(':search_query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $statement->execute();
  if($statement->rowCount())
  {
      $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      header('Content-type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($row_all);

 }  
 elseif(!$statement->rowCount())
 {
     echo "no rows";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: this inst good approach how much data do you have in db.

Comment: Well it depends how many users register in my app.

Comment: Are you doing this search for login purpose?

Comment: No, i'm doing this search for searching users in DB and sending them invites.

Answer (score 0):

If you want clear list when no results are found. You need change your code in PHP side.

```
echo "no rows";
```

to

```
echo json_encode([]);
```

> If you want to use full-text search in MySQL you need to use FULLTEXT index for column `name`